# Input focus doesnt work / can't select radio button - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following html code which uses twitter bootstrap framework, where I am not able to select the input fields,its focus gets removed when I click on it and also I am not able to select a radio button.Even if I select one,it moves to the first radio button and Im not able to select the second one.Please help me resolve this issue.And the main thing is that this is happening in firefox browser and in chrome and IE its working fine!

```
<form action="test.php" style="border: solid 1px #eee;box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;margin-top:20px" class="panel-body" method="POST" id="myForm" data-validate="parsley">
    <div id="alert" style="display:none" class="alert alert-danger text-center">Please enter a valid card number !</div>
        <div>
            <div class="col-md-4">        
                <input type="radio" data-required="true" name="cardType" id="one" class="" value="CC"><label for="radio43" class="css-label cb3">Credit Card</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="radio" name="cardType" id="one" class="" value="DB"><label for="radio53" class="css-label cb3">Debit Card</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="certificate.png" width="120" class="bw">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Card Payment -->
        <div id="a">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>

            <input type="hidden" id="ccType" name="ccType">

            <ul style="float:right;display:none" class="cards">
                <li class="visa"></li>
                <li class="visa_electron"></li>
                <li class="mastercard"></li>
                <li class="maestro"></li>           
            </ul>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Card number</label>
                    <div class="fake-input">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control zwitch_data" autocomplete="off" data-required="true" data-trigger="change" id="ccnumber" name="ccnumber" onblur="testCreditCard () ">        
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="exampleInputPassword1">CVV</label><input type="password" maxlength="4" class="form-control" data-required="true" data-trigger="change">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Expiry Month</label>
                        <select name="expiry_month" class="form-control" data-required="true" data-trigger="change">
                            <option value="01">January</option>
                            <option value="02">February</option>
                            <option value="03">March</option>
                            <option value="04">April</option>
                            <option value="05">May</option>
                            <option value="06">June</option>
                            <option value="07">July</option>
                            <option value="08">August</option>
                            <option value="09">September</option>
                            <option value="10">October</option>
                            <option value="11">November</option>
                            <option value="12">December</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Expiry Year</label>
                        <select name="expiry_year" class="form-control" data-required="true" data-trigger="change">
                            <option selected="" value="2012">2012</option>
                            <option value="2013">2013</option>
                            <option value="2014">2014</option>
                            <option value="2015">2015</option>
                            <option value="2016">2016</option>
                            <option value="2017">2017</option>
                            <option value="2018">2018</option>
                            <option value="2019">2019</option>
                            <option value="2020">2020</option>
                            <option value="2021">2021</option>
                            <option value="2022">2022</option>
                            <option value="2023">2023</option>
                            <option value="2024">2024</option>
                            <option value="2025">2025</option>
                            <option value="2026">2026</option>
                            <option value="2027">2027</option>
                            <option value="2028">2028</option>
                            <option value="2029">2029</option>
                            <option value="2030">2030</option>
                            <option value="2031">2031</option>
                            <option value="2032">2032</option>
                            <option value="2033">2033</option>
                            <option value="2034">2034</option>
                            <option value="2035">2035</option>
                            <option value="2036">2036</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Name on Card</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_on_card" data-required="true" data-trigger="change">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <input type="hidden" name="ak" value="">
                         <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00">
                         <input type="hidden" name="app" value="Checkout">
                         <input type="hidden" name="orderID" value="123456">
                         <input type="hidden" name="email" value="">
                         <input type="hidden" name="mobileNo" value="9999999999">                        
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12"> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block m-b-sm">Pay</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- Card payments ends here -->
```

Comment: Working find without twitter bootstrap framework here...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted, per se.

I personally prefer to wrap radio input buttons in the label tag without the for="" attribute. This makes it so clicking on the text also selects the radio button. Like so:

```
<label class="css-label cb3">
    <input type="radio" data-required="true" name="cardType" id="one" class="" value="CC">
    Credit Card
</label>
```

I tested your code in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dpj3m/) (granted, I added my radio button change) and it seems to work. There must be something else in your code that is causing the issue. You could try posting a link to your development website.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered probably same problem. Don't use "contenteditable='true'" property.

ERROR EXAMPLE:

```
<div class="input" contenteditable="true">
     <label for="RadioOne"><input type="radio" value="val1" name="radio" id="RadioOne">Radio 1</label>
        <label for="RadioTwo"><input type="radio" value="val2" name="radio" id="RadioTwo">Radio 2</label>
</div>
```

In your case if it isn't "contenteditable" search for other attributes which could interfere.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your question, not in the code. Radio buttons all have the same name and are treated as a group. This is why the first one is selected with a tab, then to get to individual buttons with the arrow keys. I might have misunderstood the question but I hope its useful.

g